# Correct way to put NSString inside NSMutableArray inside a method

Tags: objective-c

Consider the following codes

```
- (void) method1
{

list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *f =[[NSString alloc] initWithCString: "f"];

 [list addObject: f];
}

- (void) method2...
```

list is an instance variable of a class, I need to access all the variable inside the list in another method such as **method2**, when I alloc a NSString in **method1**, should I need to retain it? I found that that no retain is needed? Why?

Comment: `-initWithCString:` is deprecated because results may vary according to the user's default character encoding.  Either just use a straight literal `NSString *f = @"f";` or use `-initWithCString:encoding:` or use `-initWithUTF8String:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `alloc` something, you're the owner already, so there's no need to `retain` it.

Look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for the full story.

Your method (and class) is actually poorly written with regards to memory management. You should:

1. release the `list` before allocating and assigning a new list to it
2. release the `list` in the `dealloc` method
3. release the string after you add it to the array

So change your methods to:

```
- (void) method1 {  
  [list release];
  list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSString *f = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString: "f"];
  [list addObject: f];
  [f release];
}

- (void) dealloc {
  [list release];
  // release other instance variables...
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Why I need to release f at the end of method1?

Comment: Exactly, since you _own_ f (you `alloc`ed it), it's _your_ responsibility to `release` it.

Comment: And the array will retain `f` for itself.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to an @ for that string @"f"

and this covers the memory management issue
[NSMutableArray memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456233/nsmutablearray-memory-management)

Comment: You won't need a `@` since he's initializing with a C string, not an NSString.

Comment: He's using `initWithCString:`, so an @ is inappropriate.  Keep in mind, though that this is a *deprecated method*, so @Howard, don't use it!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to retain it, as you are the owner when you `alloc` a class and receive an instance. You will actually need to release it after adding to NSMutableArray. When adding objects to `NSMutableArray`, it sends them a `retain` message and takes ownership.

Also, note that initWithCString is deprecated. Use the following pattern instead if you need to init from a C string:

```
[NSString stringWithCString:"f" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But if you're just creating a constant NSString, just use the literal. It's automatically auto-released and makes your intent more clear. i.e.:

```
list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
[list addObject:@"f"];
```

Comment: >> When adding objects to NSMutableArray, it sends them a retain message and takes ownership. - Any document about this?

Comment: @Howard: You actually don't need this information. What's important to know is that, since you _own_ f, you _must_ release it. You don't need to know how _other_ code works to write _your_ code correctly.