# NSMutableArray: addObjectsFromArray retaining

Tags: nsmutablearray, retain

I am calling [array addObjectsFromArray:dictionary.allValues]
Will each copied object have retain count incremented for it? 
My understanding that when I do [array addObject:obj] , it will retain obj for me untill I delete obj from array or release array itself. Was wondering if its the same with addObjectsFromArray

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this :

[NSMutableArray memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456233/nsmutablearray-memory-management)

Regarding the object creation methods, all of the convenience methods (array:, arrayWithObjects:, arrayWithArray:, etc.) return autoreleased objects. However, their corresponding init methods (init:, initWithObjects:, initWithArray:, etc.) do not - if you call them, you are responsible for calling release on the returned object

Answer (score 0):

function that begin with init,copy,add etc always increments the retain counter of the corresponding object.If you are done with and object you should release it adterr adding to an nsmutablearray